# Counting values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows.

```
dictA = { 
    'a' : ('duck','duck','goose'), 
    'b' : ('goose','goose'), 
    'c' : ('duck','duck','duck'), 
    'd' : ('goose'), 
    'e' : ('duck','duck') 
    }
```

I'm hoping to loop through dictA and output a list that will show me the keys in dictA that have more than one "duck" in value.

For example, for dictA this function would output the below list.

```
list = ['a', 'c', 'e']
```

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I'm new to Python and this has me stumped.

Comment: Can you maybe accept an answer to mark the question as resolved? This will help other users as well.

Answer (score 13):

```
[k for (k, v) in dictA.iteritems() if v.count('duck') > 1]
```

Comment: This is a great way of doing it; only in Python 3.3 there is no dict.iteritems() and you just have to replace it with dict.items().

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good way for beginners. Don't call your list `list` - there is a builtin called `list`

```
>>> dictA = { 
...     'a' : ('duck','duck','goose'), 
...     'b' : ('goose','goose'), 
...     'c' : ('duck','duck','duck'), 
...     'd' : ('goose'), 
...     'e' : ('duck','duck') 
...     }
>>> my_list = []
>>> for key in dictA:
...     if dictA[key].count('duck') > 1:
...         my_list.append(key)
... 
>>> my_list
['a', 'c', 'e']
```

Next stage is to use `.items()` so you don't need to look the value up for each key

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> for key, value in dictA.items():
...     if value.count('duck') > 1:
...         my_list.append(key)
... 
>>> my_list
['a', 'c', 'e']
```

When you understand that, you'll find the list comprehension in Ignacio's answer easier to understand.

Comment: @jurgenreza, before list comprehensions came along, this _was_ the Pythonic way.

Comment: My bad. Nothing non-Pythonic with your code. Just got over-excited when I saw the comprehension solution.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the heck of it - here is the other, *other* way:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [i for i in dictA if Counter(dictA[i])['duck'] > 1]
['a', 'c', 'e']
```

[`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is for - you guessed it - counting things.