# How to find the total number of the same dictionary value?

Tags: python

What is the best way to find the total number of each value in dictionary variable?

This is my dictionary variable.

```
my_dict = {
        'mike':'football',
        'jack':'basketball',
        'tom':'basketball',
        'keanu':'basketball',
        'jason':'football'
}
```

And this is the output that i want.

```
Total number of each value

football : 2
basketball : 3
```

Comment: See more details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371856 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743454

Answer (score 2):

You could use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

my_dict = {
        'mike':'football',
        'jack':'basketball',
        'tom':'basketball',
        'keanu':'basketball',
        'jason':'football'
}
print(Counter(my_dict.values()))
```

Result:

```
Counter({'basketball': 3, 'football': 2})
```